# using spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate insertbatch method, insert object that have inner object

Tags: java, spring, oop, jdbc, batch-insert

I'm using Spring-boot and Oracle and I want to insert in to my database table new record using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` `insertbatch` method.

but my `object(ProductMarket)` have inner `object(Market)` with the value I need (getMarket().getId())

how can I tell `SqlParameterSource` to take the market id from the inner `Object`?

```
package x.dao.productMarket;

import java.util.List;

import x.model.base.ProductMarket;

public interface IProductMarketDao {

    public static final String INSERT_PRODUCT_MARKETS =
        " INSERT " +
        " INTO PRODUCT_MARKETS" +
        " (" +
        "    product_id ," +
        "    market_id" +
        " )" +
        " VALUES" +
        " (" +
        "    :productId ," +
        "    :marketId " +
        " ) ";


    void insert(List < ProductMarket > productMarkets);

}



package x.dao.productMarket;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSourceUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import x.model.base.ProductMarket;

@
Repository
public class ProductMarketDao implements IProductMarketDao {

    @
    Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;


    @
    Override
    public void insert(List < ProductMarket > productMarkets) {
        SqlParameterSource[] batch =
            SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(productMarkets.toArray());
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(INSERT_PRODUCT_MARKETS,
            batch);
    }
}

package x.model.base;

public class ProductMarket implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 421870753189756693 L;

    private long productId;
    private Market market;

    /**
     * @return the productId
     */
    public long getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }
        /**
         * @param productId the productId to set
         */
    public void setProductId(long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }


    public Market getMarket() {
        return market;
    }
    public void setMarket(Market market) {
        this.market = market;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are u using spring-boot?

Comment: @lolo yes i am using spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the definition of market is as follows:

```
class Market {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public Market(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you can change your SQL template as follows:

```
static final String INSERT_PRODUCT_MARKETS =
        " INSERT " +
                " INTO product_markets" +
                " (" +
                "    product_id ," +
                "    market_id" +
                " )" +
                " VALUES" +
                " (" +
                "    :productId ," +
                "    :market.id " +
                " ) ";
```

Notice how I use a path to represent the named parameter in the form `:market.id` where `market` is the name of the field in `ProductMarket` and `id` is the name of field in `Market`.

Once defined in this way, the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` will be able to dereference the corresponding value and use it as the argument for the query.